# Passing 1 viewbag 2 lists to 1 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, viewbag

I would like to show personal infos,recent appointments and incoming appointments in one page(dashboard page).Here is my controller I get error "unreachable code detected"

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace DentAppSys.Controllers
    {
        public class PatientController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Patient/
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                if (Session["UserEmail"] != null)
                {
                    string Email = (string)Session["UserEmail"];

                    using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                    {
                        var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                        ViewBag.FirstName = patient.Name;
                        ViewBag.LastName = patient.Surname;
                        ViewBag.BirthDate = patient.Birthday;
                        ViewBag.Email = patient.Email;


                    }

                    using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                    {
                        var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                        var listincoming = (from y in db.Appointments
                                          where y.PatientNo == patient.PatientNo
                                          where y.Date > DateTime.Today
                                          orderby y.Date descending
                                          select y).Take(5);

                        var TempIncoming = new List<Models.AppModel>();
                        foreach (var item in listincoming)
                        {
                            var Temp = new Models.AppModel();
                            Temp.AppNo= item.AppNo;
                            Temp.PatientNo = (Int32)item.PatientNo;
                            Temp.Date = (DateTime)item.Date;
                            Temp.Status = item.Status;
                            Temp.Description = item.Description;
                            TempIncoming.Add(Temp);


                        }
                        return View(TempIncoming);
                    }

                    using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                    {
                        var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                        var listrecent = (from y in db.Appointments
                                          where y.PatientNo == patient.PatientNo
                                          where y.Date < DateTime.Today
                                          orderby y.Date descending
                                          select y).Take(5); 

                        var TempRecent = new List<Models.AppModel>();
                        foreach (var item in listrecent)
                        {
                            var Temp = new Models.AppModel();
                            Temp.AppNo = item.AppNo;
                            Temp.PatientNo = (Int32)item.PatientNo;
                            Temp.Date = (DateTime)item.Date;
                            Temp.Status = item.Status;
                            Temp.Description = item.Description;
                            TempRecent.Add(Temp);

                        }
                        return View(TempRecent);
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("RegAndLogin", "User");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and here is my model to pass two list to view

```
namespace DentAppSys.Models
{
    public class RecentIncoming {


            public IEnumerable<DentAppSys.Models.AppModel> RecentAppts {get; set;}
            public IEnumerable<DentAppSys.Models.AppModel> IncomingAppt {get; set;}

     }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error should be gone after removing the doubly section.

Comment: You can't use multiple returns in one method. The code after a return is not executed. In your case you have to create an object that contains both lists you want to pass to your view, so you only need one return with that object.